# hashed password

Tags: java, cryptography, passwords

I have been playing around with the code found [here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/05/secure-password-storage-donts-dos-and.html). I'm getting things like

```
UKepQT7tW8mGtOJzNaLV2X+Ij/E=
```

when I view the hashed password using

```
String t = base64EncoderDecoder.encodeAsString(f.generateSecret(spec).getEncoded());
```

for my hashed password. Should it have symbols like +/= ? Also I expected the hash to be longer. Did I screw something up?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should it have symbols like +/= ?

Well, according to what should have been the first Google result (the [Wikipedia article on Base64 encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)), `+` and `/` are valid symbols that are mapped to 62 and 63 respectively.  `=` is a padding character.

> Also I expected the hash to be longer.

Why?  It's just a consequence of the encoding method you're using.  Encoding something in base 16 will take 50% more characters (since it takes 1 character per 4 bits, instead of 1 character per 6 bits).  From the very reference you cite:

> ```
> // SHA-1 generates 160 bit hashes, so that's what makes sense here
> ```

160 bits results in a 27 character Base64 encoding (160/6 ~= 27), which is what you have, so it seems reasonable to me.